# How can an iterator be returned from a function/method?

Tags: c++, iterator, set

I am trying to understand how an iterator can be a return type but I am unable to do so. I know that in class set, the `find()` method returns an iterator but when I encapsulate set class in a wrapper `Set` class, I am unable to return the iterator. Why is this so?

```
Body of Set class
...
typedef typename set<T>::iterator SetIterator; //No issue
SetIterator Find(T data); //No issue
...

Implementation
...
template <class T>
SetIterator Set<T>::Find(T data) //SetIterator does not name a type error message
{
    SetIterator i = dataSet.find(data);
    return i;
}
```

Can anyone explain what have I not done correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide the scope from where the program shall take 'SetIterator' name. `MyClass<T>::SetIterator`

```
#include <set>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class MyClass {
   typedef typename set<T>::iterator SetIterator;
   SetIterator Find(T data);
private:
   set<T> dataSet;
};

template<typename T>
MyClass<T>::SetIterator MyClass<T>::Find(T data)
{
   SetIterator i = dataSet.find(data);
   return i;
}
```

Comment: You need to say `typename` before the return type, in the implementation.

Comment: @cigien Thanks. It works after adding "typename" before vamirio-chan's MyClass<T>::SetIterator MyClass<T>::Find(T data)

Comment: @vamirio-chan Why is adding the scope required in this scenario? I'd like to understand more in depth about when I should provide the scope when I use a typedef typename.

Comment: @JinYuChan because your typedef exists only inside the scope of your class. Outside this scope the program doesn't know about this typedef. Return type is considered as global-scope value, i.e. you can determine return type (using decltype() for instance) in any given part of your code that can call this method. Except return value everything else in methods is considered as class scope so you don't need to write scope operator inside methods or its argument lists (brackets).
P.s. starting from C++14 you can just use auto.

Answer (score 0):

`SetIterator` is in the class's scope. Until `MyClass<T>::`, names won't be resolved as if in the class scope. So either specify the class manually:

```
template<typename T>
typename MyClass<T>::SetIterator MyClass<T>::Find(T data) {
    // ...
}
```

Or use a trailing return type:

```
template<typename T>
auto MyClass<T>::Find(T data) -> SetIterator {  // Resolved as `MyClass<T>::SetIterator`
    // ...
}
```

(And in this case, you can just use `auto`, as it would be deduced as `SetIterator` from the return statement)